# video breaking out of container div on iPad

Tags: html, css

I have a video on my website that is used as a full screen header background.

On desktop this works perfectly and is responsive. On `iPad`, the video works, but the video breaks out of the div and forces the page wider than 100% width.

You don't see this when you load the page, but if you swipe left/right, you see that the video is wider than the page, and the containing div isn't hiding the overflow.

```
<div id="main_video_container">
  <video loop muted autoplay poster="videobg.png" class="main_video">
    <source src="videobg.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
    <source src="videobg.webm" type="video/webm"/>
  </video>
</div>

#main_video_container {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 10;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.main_video {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  z-index: 10;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  background-size: cover;
}
```